# Odoo 8 many2many field outside form when visible

Tags: many-to-many, odoo, odoo-8

I developed a module that creates a songbook on-the-fly. Based on the song_id it loads the verses of that song in the next many2many field. Sometimes, a song does not have verses and in that case the field is not visible.

```xml
<page string="Liturgy Morning">
    <field name="liturgy_morning_line">
        <form string="Liturgy Morning Lines">
            <group>
                <group>
                    <field name="song_id"/>
                </group>
            </group>
        </form>
        <tree string="Liturgy Morning Lines" editable="bottom">
            <field name="sequence" widget="handle"/>
            <field name="song_id" options="{'no_quick_create':True,'no_create_edit':True}"/>
            <field name="has_songverses" invisible="1"/>
            <field name="songverse_ids" widget="many2many_tags" options="{'no_quick_create':True, 'no_create_edit': True}" domain="[('song_id', '=', song_id)]" attrs="{'invisible':[('has_songverses','=',False)]}"/>
         </tree>
     </field>
</page>
```

Note the "**attrs="{'invisible':[('has_songverses','=',False)]}"**" in the code. The model has a field 'has_songverses' which checkes if a song has verses or not. In case the song has no verses the field is invisible.

My issue is as follows: in case a song has verses the many2many field with song verses is loaded outside the form (see attached screenshot). IMAGE:
 [many2many field with song verses is loaded outside the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZuaP.png)

If I click again in the form the field is correctly rendered inside the form.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?
Thanks in advance!